# Display random posts, but omit the post it is on?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I am trying to have a section under a single post where it displays completely random posts. I got everything working, but every once in a while one of the random posts that get displayed is the actual post that it is on (the single).

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 3, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
$rand_posts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $rand_posts as $post ) : ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Is there anyway to not have it ever display the post it is on?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if you have a post ID (which you should on a single post page but I am not sure if this is in `single.php` or some other template like `index.php`) and add that to the `$args` if you do.

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 3, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
if (is_singular() && isset($post->ID)) {
  $args['exclude'] = array($post->ID);
}
$rand_posts = get_posts( $args );
```

### Reference

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

Answer (score 1):

Just before this you can run `<?php print_r( $post ); ?>` and if it returns an array, then you can add a parameter `'exclude' => $post->id,`

Remove the `print_r();` function after you've tested.

Comment: I ran the function and it returned something:   

 `WP_Post Object ( [ID] => 489 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2013-03-11 22:54:27 [post_date_gmt] => 2013-03-11 22:54:27 [post_content] =>` 

and then I put in `$args = array( 'numberposts' => 3, 'exclude' => $post->id,'orderby' => 'rand' );` 

and it still showed the single in the random posts